# Can a path in a URI contain unicode?

Tags: url, unicode, uri

Is it possible for a valid URL to contain non-escaped Unicode characters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the subset of ASCII (and therefore Unicode) that is allowed unescaped in URIs, such as letters and numbers. But the majority of the Unicode character set has to be percent-encoded.

Comment: Heh, smart answer.  All of the allowed unescaped characters in RFC 3986 are indeed Unicode characters.  They are all ASCII characters, too.  It is common for people to think of Unicode as being somehow non-ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

`URI` and `URL` do not natively support unescaped non-ASCII Unicode characters, however many servers do allow percent-encoded UTF-8 or localized Ansi octets to be used (but no way of specifying which is actually used).  For standardized native Unicode handling, use [`IRI`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt) instead, which is the new protocol that replaces `URI`/`URL`. It requires UTF-8 encoding for everything, and provides rules for how to convert between `IRI` and `URI`.